# Show that if $\sup\big\{\sum\lvert\, f(a)\rvert\big\} < \infty$, then $\{ a \in A : f(a) > 0\}$ is countable.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Let $f:A \to \mathbb R$ and suppose that $$
\sup\Big\{\sum_{a\in F}\lvert\, f(a)\rvert : 
F\text{ is finite subset of }A\Big\} < \infty
$$ then the set $\{ a \in A : f(a) > 0\}$ is countable.

My try: Define these element of ${ a ∈ A : f(a) > 0}$, then $∑_{n=1}^\infty\lvert\, f(a_n)\rvert$ is determined, regardless of the method of arrangement.

Comment: Hint: Countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: @i707107 Hint: Countable union of *finite* sets is countable.

Answer (score 4):

Assume that the set $P=\{a\in A:f(a)>0\}$ is uncountable. Set $P_n=\{a\in A:f(a)>1/n\}$. Then
clearly
$$
P=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}P_n.
$$
If all $P_n$'s were countable, then so would be $P$, as a countable union of countable sets. Hence, for some $n_0$, then set $P_{n_0}$ is uncountable.

Clearly
$$
\sum_{a\in P_{n_0}}f(a)\ge \sum_{a\in P_{n_0}}\frac{1}{n_0}=\infty.
$$

Comment: You can even be more stringent: All the $P_n$ have to be finite. If the sup in the definition is $M$, then $P_n$ can not have more than $[Mn]$ elements.

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann Can you elaborate on why is the cardinality of $P_n \le [Mn]$?

Comment: @user13 If it were larger, then for any subset $F$ of $[Mn]+1$ elements, the sum would have a lower bound larger than the supremum, $$\sum_{a\in F}f(a)\ge([Mn]+1)\frac1n>\frac{Mn}n=M.$$

Comment: Thank you. However, I still don't understand why are you writing $\sum_{a\in F}f(a) \ge ([Mn] + 1)1/n$? How do you know that? Is there some theorem, that states that the sum over the set is no less than the cardinality times some element of the set?