# Show that if sup{∑|f(a)|}<∞, then {a∈A:f(a) is not zer0} is countable.

Tags: real-analysis

Let f:A→R and suppose that sup{∑a∈F|f(a)|:F is finite subset of A}<∞ then {a∈A:f(a)is not zero} is countable.

and show that Define these element of { a ∈ A : f(a) is not 0} a1, a2, a3, ... then ∑(n=1 to infinity)|f(an)| is determined, Regardless of the method of arrange

---

Its question may similar to [Show that if $\sup\big\{\sum\lvert\, f(a)\rvert\big\} < \infty$, then $\{ a \in A : f(a) > 0\}$ is countable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792738/show-that-if-sup-sumfa-infty-then-a-in-a-fa-0-is-co)

Comment: Not similar, exact duplicate. As it stands now, at least.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Show that $\{a\in A:f(a)>\frac{1}{n}\}$ is a finite set for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and use the fact that countable union of finite sets is countable.

Comment: Thanks and i have second question. I think its very clear. But i dont know how to prove.

Comment: @user140794: Assume that there are infinitely many $a_{1},a_{2},...\in A$ with $f(a_{k})>\frac{1}{n}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $\sup_{N\in\mathbb{N}}\sum_{k=1}^{N}f(a_{k})=\infty$, which is a contradiction to your assumption. And note for the last part: for absolutely convergent series the order of terms doesn't affect the sum.